# How to get rid of header menu item

Tags: html, css

I have a header menu item (contact) in my WordPress site that keeps popping up intermittently. Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Tried:

```css
.menu-item-3530 {
  display: none! important;
}
```

```html
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown"><a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact 
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
<li id="menu-item-12515" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12515"><a title="DRAWING DEVELOPMENT" href="https://4309.co.uk/drawing-development/">DRAWING DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
```

But using the above css hides the whole menu, and not just header `contact` item.

[here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: the bits of code you shared does what is supposed to. Some html is missing here to eventually reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML code you provide, the `<a>` tag is not properly closed, which may cause some unwanted behaviour. Try closing the `<a>` and `<li>` tags before the `<ul>` tag by adding `</a></li>` at the end of the line :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown"><a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Which tag where?

Comment: It's also just an html snippet to illustrate. Can't change html as it's WordPress

Comment: `A` tag before `li` tag you mean?

Comment: On the first line of the snippet you provided, both **a** and **li** tags aren't closed.

Comment: By open you mean `<foobar` and by closed you mean `<foobar>`?

Comment: Open would be `<foobar>` and closed would be `</foobar>`. I added both missing closing tags in the answer : `</a></li>` after `Contact`

Comment: Ah, thanks. I see. Hmm, to edit might be difficult as i think I'd have to edit php, which i don't know how to do. Any css solutions or reasons why hiding one menu item hides whole menu and all menu items? Because if i try to hide any other menu item, it doesn't hide whole menu in the process....

Comment: Well, since the tags aren't closed, the browser actually considers that the whole menu is part of this one menu item, which explains why the whole menu gets hidden. So no, i'm afraid you won't fix that with some css...